# Response for missing resources?

Tags: rest, conventions

I am creating a simple REST API that outputs JSON data. However I am not sure what should be returned if I make an request to a resource which has no data to return:

What of the below shown alternatives would be appropriate to use when requesting `/users` and `/users/:id` when there are no users at all, or the specific user can't be found?

1. `[]` and `HTTP 200`
2. Empty response with a  `HTTP 410 - Gone` ?
3. Empty response with a `HTTP 404 - missing`
4. Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GET /users` should return a `HTTP 200` with a response of `[]` or a `HTTP 204` with an empty response.

`GET /users/:id` should return a `HTTP 404`. You can return a custom error message as the response if you want.